# Temperature detection > device with adjustable temperature

Tags: thermal-imaging

I'm working on a software that measures the facial skin temperature, a kind of 'fever detector';
In order to test the software, I want to check if my detector correctly works with objects with temperatures around 37.5 - 39 C, but I cannot find a 'device' that can be used for such measurements. A kind of thermostat, but it should keep static temperature on its outer shell.
I tried to use a cup with hot water, but its temperature is being decreasing too fast, I would like to have an object with static temperature.
Any advices on which device or object can be used are highly appreciated.

PS Soldering iron and Curling Hair with adjustable temperatures are working in too high temperatures range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small objects (like an 8 oz/237 ml ) cup of hot water will lose heat quickly, especially if uninsulated, so will exhibit a quick drop in temperature.

A larger warm mass will hold its temperature for a longer period of time, as will an insulated mass. Therefore, use a vacuum-insulated ('Thermos'TM) bottle filled with warm water for your calibration.

Comment: Please also see https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers